# prevent jqGrid onSelectRow from being called for particular cell - jqGrid v4.4.4

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my jqGrid I have `onSelectRow` and `onCellSelect` events implemented. `onCellSelect` is for one particular cell only. When I click on that cell first `onCellSelect` event fires followed by `onSelectRow`. But I want only `onCellSelect` event to be fired for that cell alone. For other cells in the grid its fine. My approach to this problem is calling `beforeSelectRow` event. In the event I find the cell then set my javascript variable to false. Then in `onSelectRow` check if this value is true only then execute the statements in `onSelectRow`, else ignore them.

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                    var $self = $(this),
                    iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]),
                    cm = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
                    if (cm[iCol].name === "Activate/Deactivate") {
                        selectRow = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        selectRow = true;
                    }
                    return true;
                },                                              
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
                    var row = $(this).getRowData(rowid);
                    if (iCol == 7) {
                        //some code statements here
                        });
                    }
                }, 
onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (selectRow) {
                       //some code statements here
                    }
                },
```

Is there any other better approach to this? (selectRow is a variable outside jqGrid)

Comment: Please describe which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid version <=4.7?

Comment: Please include in the text of every question about jqGrid the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Your current code of `beforeSelectRow` uses `return true;` instead of `return selectRow;` (`selectRow` could be local variable). Moreover, I don't see any reason to separate your code in 3 callbacks. You can place all the code inside of `beforeSelectRow`.

Comment: @Tony I'm using the jQuery.jqGrid (by Trirand) nuget package in my ASP.NET MVC application. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/4.4.4)

Comment: @Oleg I'm using the jQuery.jqGrid (by Trirand) nuget package in my ASP.NET MVC application. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/4.4.4)

Comment: @NoahSunil: jqGrid 4.4.4 is retro version, published more as 4.5 years ago and it's dead since many years. Currently there are two main forks: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop and which is available as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) too, and commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov. I recommend you to upgrade to the latest version of one from the products.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks!. I just installed the free-jqGrid Nuget package. The **TypeScript** file, freejqGrid.ts thrown a lot of errors. I'm not using TypeScript in my project so removed that file and it build successfully. This version of jqGrid is loading faster than the previous one. I don't see any compatibility issues. I'm using the same jQuery code for v4.4.4 here. Amazing work guys! I would recommend it.

Comment: @NoahSunil: You can remove .ts file, which you not need or to follow the steps described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/353#issuecomment-323547393)

Answer (score 1):

Basically if Guriddo jqGrid is used the code in beforeSelectRow can be moved in onSelectRow, since this method has the event parameter too.

There is a much eiser way to det the name of the cell selected.

Try this

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
....
}, 
onSelectRow: function (id, status, e) {
    var name = $(e.target).closest("td").attr('aria-describedby'); 
    name = name.split(this.p.id+"_");
    name = name[1];
    if (name === "Activate/Deactivate") {
       //some code statements here
    }
},
```

Comment: Just for information the above code will work in jqGrid version 4.4.4.